# Remove Cents (Round Up to Nearest Dollar) on WooCommerce Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rounding, orders

Currently using the following code to round up the display price, however the order that gets created and all order emails do not round the totals. Any way to keep round numbers on every order that does not revert back after order is placed?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'round_price_product' 
);
function round_price_product( $price ){
    // Return rounded price
    return round( $price );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total filter hook rounding Order total price just before it's formatted for display on Order total row:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total', 'round_formatted_order_total', 10, 2 );
function round_formatted_order_total( $formatted_total, $order ) {

    $formatted_total = wc_price( round( $order->get_total() ), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );

    return $formatted_total;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

---

Or if you need to round all Order totals, you will use `woocommerce_get_order_item_totals` hook instead, where you will have to round all the rows you need.

In the example below, subtotal and total rows will be rounded:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'rounded_formatted_order_totals', 10, 3 );
function rounded_formatted_order_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    $tax_display = $tax_display ? $tax_display : get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_display_cart' );

    // For subtotal line
    if ( isset( $total_rows['cart_subtotal'] ) ) {
        $subtotal    = 0;
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $subtotal += $item->get_subtotal();
            if ( 'incl' === $tax_display ) {
                $subtotal += $item->get_subtotal_tax();
            }
        }
        $subtotal = wc_price( round( $subtotal ), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
        if ( 'excl' === $tax_display && $this->get_prices_include_tax() ) {
            $subtotal .= ' <small class="tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
        }
        $total_rows['cart_subtotal']['value'] = $subtotal;
    }

    // For total line
    if ( isset( $total_rows['order_total'] ) ) {
        $total = wc_price( round( $order->get_total() ), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
        $total_rows['order_total']['value'] = $total;
    }

    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.